# How to verify if element only contains text without any tag in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver to verify the cell from a table that cell only contains text only without any tags like span, link,  or i . I want to return true when only hit td[3] field 3 so far I only use

```
t = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//table/tbody//tr/td').text
if not t:
    print('no text')
else:
    print('yes text only')
    print(t)
```

but it does not work

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a>link text</a>
        <div>name</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>field 2</div>
        <!--react text -->
        field 2 number
        <!-- / react text -->
    </td>
    <td>
        field 3
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <button>
                <i>...</i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                text under button
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>field 5</div>
    </td>
</tr>

//*[@id="app"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a
//*[@id="app"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div
//*[@id="app"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div
//*[@id="app"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]
//*[@id="app"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div/button/i
//*[@id="app"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div/div/div[1]
//*[@id="app"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code once, it may help you.

```
 List<WebElement> rows=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table/tbody//tr/td"));
    for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++){
    t=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table/tbody//tr/td["+i+"]").getText();
        if("".equals(t)||t==null){
            System.out.println("no text");
        }else{
            System.out.println("yes text only");
            System.out.println(t);}
```